# How do I make a mathematica cdf which imports data and plot them?

Tags: visualization, gui-construction

I have a python program which could browse for an excel file containing data, load them such that each column is automatically recognized and then make 3D graph or density plot from the loaded data. Meanwhile, it has different TABS: The first tab selects three colums (eg x, y and f(x,y)) and make a 3D graph of f against x and y (with colored legend on the right).
The 2nd tab selects three colums (eg x, z and g(x,y)) and make a density plot of g against x and z (with colored legend on the right).
The 3rd tab when clicked selects one column as x and many other columns (it looks like y1(x), y2(x), y3(x), y4(x)); and plot these y's against x. It was designed such that in the operations, the column headings are used appropriately in all the plots (for the axes and legends).
This program was quite tormenting to develop because of the challenges with python (especially the libraries) and I have wondered how I could do this in mathematica because of the beauty of wolfram programming. I would really appreciate some directions and comments. I am ready to supply any info on my Python code.

Comment: Okay. My goal is to reproduce a standalone program in mathematica which could perform the operations as outlined above. I want to first make .nb for the program and then make a standalone cdf from the code file. Yes, I have mathematica (versions 9 and 10). The app is meant for visualization of data obtained in my institution.

Comment: If your collegues have access to mathematica then there is no problem. But you will have to do your homework about `.cdf` `Manipulate`, `DynamicModule` etc. Take a look at `TabView`, `FileNameSetter`, `Graphics3D` etc.